Hyperquadrics classification
In linear algebra, I studied that we can classify quadric surfaces (and conics) just by studying their orthogonal invariants, and we can also transform them from their original form to their canonical form (either affine or not) using only rotations and translations. My question is: can we also study hyperquadrics (with $n>3$ variables) and the transformation to their canonical form in a similar (generalized) way? Is it "useful"? P.S. by "useful" I mean: does it have any real world application or any theoretical maths application? Or it doesn't make sense to bother with this after we loose the visual intuition that we have for conics and quadrics?
